# Infinitely looping UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I am wondering if there is a way to modify a UITableView such that when you scroll past the very last cell, the cells start repeating...and you can keep scrolling indefinitely only to be presented with the same cells repeating over and over. Ideally this would also work in reverse as well (if you scrolled up instead of down).

I haven't been able to find any information on the topic online which has been leading me to think it either can't be done or is quite difficult...but I thought I would ask here to see if  anyone could help me out.

Comment: you got the solution?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite trivial actually.

What I've done in the past to achieve that effect is:

Let's assume you have a tableView with an **N** number of lines.
It will help if all lines are the same size. Let's assume **S** for the height of each.

You implement the dataSource methods like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return N*1000;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger actualRow = indexPath.row % N;

    // .. do everything using actualRow instead of indexPath.row

}
```

Now, on your viewController or something after you've set up the tableView with the delegate and dataSource and whatnot. Add this:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,500*N*S)];
```

Basically you've created a very big tableView of repeating cells, and you make it start in the middle. You'll have 500 instances to go through both on top and bottom, so you'll surely not get to the end of it. And since you will be reusing cells, this has no performance impact.